# Can't find parent div using Jquery when using jquery datepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have used a `jquery datepicker plugin` in my site.I have written such that the calender is being shown only when the `a tag` is clicked.What is need is that,once i click a date in the calender i need to get the parent div of the `datepicker`. So I wrote the following script.I cant get the div named `self_calender` which is my fourth parent.I get a `undefined` alert when i try to alert it using `Jquery`.Could someone tel me a method so that i could get the parent `div` within which the `datepicker` is enclosed...

```
<a href="" title="calendar" class="calendar">calendar</a>
    <div id="self_calender">
        // Jquery date Picker
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default').live('click',function(){
        alert($(this).parents().eq(4).html());
})
```

Comment: Could you post the rendered html instead?

Comment: Why not use closest("#self_calender")?
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Also which jQuery version are you using? `.live()` is deprecated as of version 1.7. Use `.on()` instead when attaching event handlers.

Comment: @mishik Why even use `closest` is the thing is an `id`? There should only be _one_.

Comment: The input is not parent of ui-datepicker, check rendered html

Comment: @GrantThomas to ensure that it's our parent.

Comment: @mishik Irrelevant. It has a unique identifier, only one of them means it _must_ be the parent.

Comment: @mishik  GrantThomas said: why not then use $("#self_calender") as ID must be unique on context page

Comment: can you post the original html markup?

Comment: @TamilVendhan OP did, we want the rendered html client side, first comment here, still not answered

Comment: `<a href="" title="calendar" class="calendar">calendar</a>
    <div id="self_calender">
        // Jquery date Picker
    </div>` is not sufficient. What is in `// Jquery date Picker`? Just input element or input element inside nested div;s?

Comment: @roasted: No its not required, he can just use `onSelect` event of the  calander and access the parent with `$(this).parent()`, If my assumption is right.

Comment: @TamilVendhan i never said it is required, it was just to point OP than the input is not parent. You solution using onSelect callback seems good too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
$(this).closest('.ui-datepicker') // which ever selector applies to the desired element
```

Comment: Would still need the parent. Would be a simpler to do `$(this).next();`; otherwise, you need to chain `.parent();` to your solution.

Comment: @Outlooker This doesn't get the parent you said you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).live('click','.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default',function(){
        alert($(this).parents('#self_calender').html());
})
```

And if your jquery is new:

```
$(document).on('click','.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default',function(){
        alert($(this).parents('#self_calender').html());
})
```

And one more idea. Your `self_calender` is just and id, so its **should** be unique. Then:

```
$(document).on('click','.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default',function(){
            alert($('#self_calender').html());
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the element has an id this means you can use a selector specifically for that thing:

```
var container = $("#self_calendar");
```

If you have more than one of these things then you shouldn't be applying the same id, and wouldn't have the issue of possibly selecting the wrong element.

Comment: I think OP wants to know which input fired the ui-datepicker dialog if there is more than one

Answer (score 1):

Your DOM traversing is not required to achieve what you are trying to do.

If your HTML code in file looks like this:

```
<a href="" title="calendar" class="calendar">calendar</a>
  <div id="self_calender" class='targetParent'>
    <input id='dateHolder' />
</div>
```

In JS, you could use [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event of datepicker:

```
$('#dateHolder').datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
   var div = $(this).parent();
   //div is #self_calender
  }
});
```